# Uniqueidentifier fields of MS SQL table are empty when retriving them using QSqlQuery and QT 4.8.4

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, qvariant

I have the MS SQL Server 9.0.4035 on Windows machine.
I'm connecting to it using stable freetds 0.91 and unixODBC 2.2 on my OpenSUSE 12.3.
Here is the confs:

freetds.conf:

```
...
[egServer70K]
host = 192.168.16.37
instance = [my_instance]
port = 1435
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
...
```

odbc.ini :

```
[msdsn]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = MSSQL database for ay
Servername=egServer70K
```

Executing next sql query in tsql and isql I getting:

```
tsql -S egServer70K -U [login]
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> SELECT TOP(3) guid FROM [table_name] ORDER BY data_time;
2> go
guid
9A2911A6-ADE1-4AE0-B7FC-A93F7821BB1D
E2C0797E-057C-4C0E-8562-62D020C5F49C
13143608-B52B-4DBF-B571-0AD21592BABA
(3 rows affected)
```

(this means that on the level of freetds everithing's fine.)

And the same I got when I'm doing this:

```
isql -v msdsn [login] [pass]

SQL> SELECT TOP(3) guid FROM [table_name] ORDER BY data_time;

+-------------------------------------+
| guid                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| 9A2911A6-ADE1-4AE0-B7FC-A93F7821BB1D|
| E2C0797E-057C-4C0E-8562-62D020C5F49C|
| 13143608-B52B-4DBF-B571-0AD21592BABA|
+-------------------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns 3
3 rows fetched
```

(this means that on the level of the unixODBC all is ok).

But executing this lines of code in Qt 4.8.4:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
             db.setHostName("192.168.16.37");
             db.setDatabaseName("msdsn");
             db.setUserName("...");
             db.setPassword("...");

QSqlQuery q( db);
    q.exec(
      "SELECT TOP(3) guid FROM [table_name] ORDER BY data_time;");
    while( q.next()) {
        qDebug() << q.value(0);
    }
```

I got only:

```
QVariant(QString, "") 
QVariant(QString, "")
QVariant(QString, "")
```

What should I do?

PS> I can't use Qt 5.